# 1996 Toyota Avalon How to remove a dashboard?

Tags: toyota, cel, avalon, dashboard

So I came to America for two months and quickly realised that *everyone drives*. So, since I hadn't budgeted for a car I bought a cheap 1996 Toyota Avalon. Trouble is, my naivety led me to buy a car without a "SMOG" (and it failed when I had one). I've since learnt that it must have one in order to fully register the car and the first of possibly many issues with this is that there is no check engine light! So I'll probably have the mechanic fix it but I was wondering...

[image: Toyota Dash]

***How might one remove the dash board in order to access the check engine light bulb?***

I'm just curious as to whether it is friction fit or screws or something else. Just general guidelines or approach would be good.

Comment: It looks like there is a screw hole in the top of the black surround in your photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a few screws holding the black trim in marked J in the diagram as well as two screws in the upper portion of the trim. Remove the trim and any connectors. There will be four screws holding in the cluster. Remove those and you can pull the cluster out.

[image]

Comment: Nice!  if you could get some pictures, that would be even better :)